# Uploaded Image Preview

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, png, image-uploading

I use this javascript code to preview an uploaded image before sending it to server:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        if(input.files[0].type.match('image.*')){
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#logo-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
}

$("#upload-logo").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

This works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and suprisingly on IE10 and IE11.
Although, on IE I cannot read PNG images in some computers. For instance, I have 2 PCs with Windows 7 and IE11...one reads PNG images the other doesn't. 
I have no clue what is happening here. Does anybody have an idea of what may be the problem?

Comment: try clearing browser cache

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.revathskumar.com/2012/04/html5-show-thumbnail-preview-of-image.html

The url above contains a sample code, with a working demo, it is using FileReader and Canvas. I tested on IE 11, and it works. I would recommend using that sample in both computers and see if works as well.

You could also make sure that one of your computers is not running IE in compatibility view.